# JAVA - make 10 threads run simultaneously to increment counter 1-10

Tags: java, multithreading

I need 10 threads in JAVA to run simultaneously to increment counter from 1-10.

I have the code working. But, the counter is always in a different order.

```
public class Counter
{

    static Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Count c = new Count();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(c);
            threads[i].start();
        }

    }
}

public class Count implements Runnable {
    int n=1;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(n++);
    }

    public void showOutput(){
        System.out.println(n++);
    }

}
```

Output Example:2 4 3 1 5 9 8 6 7 10

Comment: You are running 10 threads (that, by definition, can finish in random order) and are getting your result in a random order. Why is that a problem?

Comment: This is exactly what one would expect from threads, there is no guarantee that one thread runs before another, nor that if a thread actually runs before another that it finishes before it.

Comment: yup, i get it. I knew this is what's happening. But my assignment says that the expected output should be 1-10 in correct sequence.

Comment: Try looking into synchronization. A tutorial like this should be helpful http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

Comment: I don't know why so many textbooks/instructors teach this crap.  All their examples of how to use threads are _horrible_ examples of when/where/why to use threads.  This exercise will teach you how to tightly synchronize threads, but what the instructor isn't telling you is that the tighter the synchronization, the less benefit there is to using threads.  In this case, the threads will be so tightly synchronized, that there is no benefit at all.  If you ever want to write a real program that does ten things in a particular order, there is only one reasonable way to do that:  use _one_ thread.

Answer (score 5):

Threads are asynchronous and work independently. **There is no guanrantee of any order of execution of anything in different threads, unless there are some synchronization methods used**. Your code works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use Join() function to run your threads in sync add the below code in your loop

```
try {
    threads[i].join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks
-vivek

Comment: This is one of the ways to execute the threads sequentially. I know that it might not serve a good performance(as the thread executes sequentially) but it does provide the solution to the problem mentioned here.

Answer (score -3):

You can use synchronized thread

```
@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    System.out.println(n++);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gurkan. But that does that make the threads run 1 by 1 or do they still run simultaneously?

Comment: Yeah, if you use synchronized threads, they will wait for each other:(